# Array access child thread java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have an array of SinglePDFPage-objects, those are just wrapper objects which each hold a WritableImage-object.

While filling it up in a loop inside a child thread, I can still access the array outside of the thread. Literally at the same time. I'm rendering WritableImage-objects which hold a single PDF-Page each. That takes about half a second each.

While filling that array up, i can access it and sort of pre-render a certain page before the child threads loop has gotten to it.

I have read about the `volatile` keyword and synchronized collections; which I thought were needed if you have objects accessed by different threads. I thought that usually the objects were written to the threads storage? If so, why can i access them without any locks or synchronizing?

Would the described pattern be "thread-safe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit abstract, so I'll address at an abstract level.

Thread-safety doesn't refer to the ability to access data across threads. It refers to doing so *safely*, that is, in such a way that other threads can't view data in an invalid state. Your code is *not* thread-safe, as indicated by the fact that other threads can see your array before it's fully populated. `volatile`, `synchronized`, concurrent collections and utilities are *tools* that help you control access to shared state between threads.

Comment: Youre right its a bit abstract. :)
What I experienced in the past is that you have to do something to make it work. Im just surprised that it works like that and am wondering why.


Its still a class variable, so if its stored in the main threads threadstorage, how can i access it at the same time?

Comment: @MasterAzazel Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: @MasterAzazel I think you may be confusing classes with threads. A class instance can encapsulate data. Threads don't. A thread's sole purpose is to execute code. Synchronization helps define the circumstances in which a thread can execute a particular piece of code.

Comment: so what would synchronizing or implementing locks do in my case? would it be better? is the way i described it the way you should do it?

Comment: @MasterAzazel You haven't actually shown any code, but from your description it sounds like you would benefit from synchronization. There are plenty of online tutorials if you want all the details.